# How to use a CASE statement after FROM before SELECT in UPDATE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case

I'm not sure if this is possible, but the essence of what I'm trying to do is have two separate `SELECTS`, one for a single result, one for the union of two results. Note: the text in {brackets} is just a generic substitution. The below gives me a syntax error at `CASE`:

```
UPDATE MySchema.MyTable as MyTable
SET {column_names} = {new values}
FROM
CASE
    WHEN {case A} THEN
        (SELECT {column_names}
        FROM MySchema.MyOtherTable
        WHERE {conditions}
        LIMIT 1)
    ELSE
        ((SELECT {column_names}
        FROM MySchema.MyOtherTable
        WHERE {conditions}
        LIMIT 1)
        UNION
        (SELECT {column_names}
        FROM MySchema.MyOtherTable
        WHERE {other_conditions}
        LIMIT 1))
END CASE;
AS MyOtherTable
WHERE MyTable.product_id = MyOtherTable.product_id
```

I've had this query working with the `UPDATE`-`SET`-`FROM` portion duplicated inside each of the two cases, but I'm trying to trim out redundancies in the query if possible. I also tried moving the `FROM` inside each case, but that gave a syntax error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `case` expression to put together the objects used in a statement. You could, however, use logical operators to emulate this construct, so the values with `{other_conditions}` are only used if `{case A}` does not occur:

```
UPDATE MySchema.MyTable as MyTable
SET {column_names} = {new values}
FROM
((SELECT {column_names}
FROM MySchema.MyOtherTable
WHERE {conditions}
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT {column_names}
FROM MySchema.MyOtherTable
WHERE (NOT ({case A})) AND ({other_conditions}) -- Here!
LIMIT 1))
```

Comment: Yes, I'd considered something similar. This is inside a trigger function, and case A is when a value is NULL in `OLD`, or is the same in `NEW` and `OLD`. Because the update is fixing a single row, or that same row plus another one. I was afraid there would be too much overhead from simply including the unioned select, but I hadn't considered the `NOT {case A}` logic. Thanks!